# away3d - 2 textures on 1 plane

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, away3d

Im trying to make plane with full (background) texture and partial (element) texture on 1 plane. Partial element will change often in runtime , so Im curious if can use kind of double drawing on single plane element ?

Is is possible ? Or I have to make 2 planes , one above another ?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to extend BitmapTexture and create a class similar to [WebcamTexture](http://away3d.com/livedocs/away3d/4.0/away3d/textures/WebcamTexture.html) where you composite the images and assign the results to the texture's bitmapdata.

Look at the update function in the [WebcamTexure class](https://github.com/away3d/away3d-core-fp11/blob/master/src/away3d/textures/WebcamTexture.as), that's where they grab the camera bitmapdata and apply it to the texture.

If autoUpdate is true the update() function is called from uploadContent(), similar to OnEnterFrame. To manually update the texture set autoUpdate to false and call update() only when needed.